# How to remove this special characters and how to avoid duplication in string variable value?

Tags: javascript

I have java script string variable with some special characters and duplicate values... i want to remove only the < and > symbols and need to avoid duplicates... how to achieve this...

this is what i have...

```
var columnname = "USER_ID,PRIORITY,CREATION_DATE<,CREATION_DATE>,ASSIGN_TO_USER_DATE<,ASSIGN_TO_USER_DATE>,START_WORK_DATE<,START_WORK_DATE>,PARTICIPANT_TYPE,SENDER_ID";
```

and it should be like this....

```
var columnname = "USER_ID,PRIORITY,CREATION_DATE,ASSIGN_TO_USER_DATE,START_WORK_DATE,PARTICIPANT_TYPE,SENDER_ID";
```

Comment: i tried giving this... var name=columnname.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g, '');   but it removing all the special characters including _ and ,

Answer (score 3):

One possible short solution:

```
columnname.replace(/[<>]/g, "").split(",").filter(function(item, i, arr) {
    return i === arr.indexOf(item);
}).join(",");
```

Note, that some old browsers might not support [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) methods. You may check for compatibility shims in *MDN*.

Answer (score 0):

I am not giving the full answer as you have not provided any code, but here are the basic steps you should follow:

- replace all unwanted characters in the string
- split the string on the comma to give you an array of values
- take out all the duplicates out of the array

Answer (score 0):

Also you may use reduce function

```
    input_string.replace(/[<>]/g, "").split(",").reduce(function(a, b) {
        a = Array.isArray(a)? a : [a];
        if(a.indexOf(b) == -1){ a.push(b);}
        return a;
    });
```